# showing another window/frame in wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython

I am fairly new to programming and to python and wxpython. I have looked over this code for literally HOURS and I tried finding an answer everywhere online. I am having trouble getting a new window to show up after a menu item is clicked. Here is my code so far...

```
import wx

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,'Python Test App',size=(600,400))
        panel=wx.Panel(self)
        wx.Frame.CenterOnScreen(self)
        ##wx.Frame.Maximize(self)

        status=self.CreateStatusBar()
        menubar=wx.MenuBar()
        file_menu=wx.Menu()
        edit_menu=wx.Menu()

        ID_FILE_NEW = 1
        ID_FILE_OPEN = 2

        ID_EDIT_UNDO = 3
        ID_EDIT_REDO = 4


        file_menu.Append(ID_FILE_NEW,"New Window","This is a new window")
        file_menu.Append(ID_FILE_OPEN,"Open...","This will open a new window")

        edit_menu.Append(ID_EDIT_UNDO,"Undo","This will undo your last action")
        edit_menu.Append(ID_EDIT_REDO,"Redo","This will redo your last undo")


        menubar.Append(file_menu,"File")
        menubar.Append(edit_menu,"Edit")
        self.SetMenuBar(menubar)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, NewWindow.new_frame, None, 1)

class NewWindow(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self,MainWindow,id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, id, 'New Window', size=(600,400))
        wx.Frame.CenterOnScreen(self)
        self.Show(False)

    def new_frame(self, event):
        NewWindow.Show(True)



if __name__=='__main__':
        app=wx.PySimpleApp()
        frame=MainWindow(parent=None,id=-1)
        frame.Show()
        app.MainLoop()
```

When I try to run this code, I get this error message once I click on the menu item "New Window"

```
TypeError: unbound method new_frame() must be called with NewWindow instance as first argument (got CommandEvent instance instead)
```

Again, I am fairly new to programming. Any help is greatly appreciated and also, I know my code may not be the "cleanest" looking code around. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a pointer, calling methods like this `wx.Frame.CenterOnScreen(self)` isn't how you typically call methods. Because you're in an instance of `wx.Frame` you have access all the methods of a frame, so you can just call `self.CenterOnScreen()`. The only time you should need to call methods like the former is if you no longer have access to the method because you have overridden it (like when calling `wx.Frame.__init__` in `__init__` for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying your code to some extent i was able to show a new window when user clicks a New Window option,

Do check the stuff that i have modified a let me know if this is what you want??

```
import wx

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,'Python Test App',size=(600,400))
        panel=wx.Panel(self)
        wx.Frame.CenterOnScreen(self)

        status=self.CreateStatusBar()
        menubar=wx.MenuBar()
        file_menu=wx.Menu()
        edit_menu=wx.Menu()

        ID_FILE_NEW = 1
        ID_FILE_OPEN = 2

        ID_EDIT_UNDO = 3
        ID_EDIT_REDO = 4


        file_menu.Append(ID_FILE_NEW,"New Window","This is a new window")
        file_menu.Append(ID_FILE_OPEN,"Open...","This will open a new window")

        edit_menu.Append(ID_EDIT_UNDO,"Undo","This will undo your last action")
        edit_menu.Append(ID_EDIT_REDO,"Redo","This will redo your last undo")


        menubar.Append(file_menu,"File")
        menubar.Append(edit_menu,"Edit")
        self.SetMenuBar(menubar)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.test, None, 1)

    def test(self, event):
        self.new = NewWindow(parent=None, id=-1)
        self.new.Show()

class NewWindow(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, 'New Window', size=(400,300))
        wx.Frame.CenterOnScreen(self)
        #self.new.Show(False)

if __name__=='__main__':
        app=wx.PySimpleApp()
        frame=MainWindow(parent=None,id=-1)
        frame.Show()
        app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't seem to understand how classes work in Python.  You try to call `NewWindow.new_frame`, but you never actually create an instance of that class.

The error message is because you are calling the method on the class instead of on an instance of the class.  What you want to do is something like:

```
newWin = NewWindow(...) # replace ... with the appropriate parameters
newWin.Show(True)
```

You don't provide enough information in your example to know what the appropriate parameters are for the NewWindow call (e.g., you don't show where you create the main window), but the `MainWindow` and `id` parameters in `NewWindow.__init__` aren't just there for looks: wxPython needs to know the parent window.  You should look into the wxPython documentation to understand how to create a wxFrame.