# Show child wx.Frame?

Tags: python, wxpython

I've got two frames – mainWindow, which is the "primary" frame, and moreWindow, which is a child of mainWindow. I'd like to show moreWindow when a button in mainWindow is clicked. Here's what I'm trying:

```
def showChild(nil):
    moreWindow.Show()
class mainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__:
        buttonMore.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, showChild)
class moreWindow(wx.Frame):

TypeError: unbound method Show() must be called with moreWindow instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

I tried using `moreWindow.Show(moreWindow)`, and that just gave a more cryptic error.

Comment: what was the error you got when you tried that ?

Comment: @mux `TypeError: unbound method Show() must be called with moreWindow instance as first argument (got type instance instead)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to call that method on an *instance* of `moreWindow`, not class `moreWindow` itself. That is, you need to create an instance of `moreWindow` somewhere in your code:

```
more_window = moreWindow()
```

And then call `show` on that instance:

```
more_window.show()
```

Also, check this answer, it's exactly what you want to do:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11201346/1157444